# The type or namespace name PlayerMotor could not be found

Tags: c#

I got this problem. I was doing it after seeing a tutorial but still it doesn't work. Error which comes is as follows :

> The type or namespace name PlayerMotor could not be found

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))]
public class PlaerController : MonoBehaviour {
    Camera cam;
    PlayerMotor motor;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
            cam = Camera.main;
            motor = GetComponents<PlayerMotor> ();
        }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
             Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);  
             RaycastHit hit;

             if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                Debug.Log ("We hit " + hit.collider.name + " " + hit.point);
                motor.MoveToPoint (hit.point);
                // Move our player to what we hit
                // Stop focusing anz objects
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So where is `PlayerMotor` defined?

Comment: Looks like you are missing namespaces. Your code shown doesn't define any namespace either...